# Google Apps Script's Logger.log() not working for doGet function in code.gs

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, logging

In a Google Apps Script project for my google sheets, in the `Code.gs` file, I have two functions - `doGet` for when standard GET requests, and `sendEmail` which has a trigger setup on it - if the google form linked to my sheet receives a new response, the trigger runs this function. Both those functions have a `Logger.log()` command at end, to keep track of runs.

Here's a basic structure of my code:

```
function doGet(request) {
  var data = request.parameter.data;
  var taskmode = request.parameter.mode;
  var dataarr = [{}];
  dataarr = data.split(" | ");
  // code...

  if(taskmode == "search") {
      // code...
      if(condition) var responsePrint = "NA";
      else var responsePrint = "Some Data";

      Logger.log(responsePrint); // does not work
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(responsePrint); //works
  } else if(taskmode == "update") {
      //some code
      if(condition) var responsePrint = "Done";
      else var responsePrint = "Not Done";

      Logger.log(responsePrint); //does not work
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(responsePrint); //works
  } else if(taskmode == "new") {
      sheet.appendRow(dataarr);
      var responsePrint = "Done";
      Logger.log(responsePrint); //doesnt work
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(responsePrint); //works
  }
  // .... +4 more such else..if conditions, which have both Logger.log() which does not work & ContentService ...() which works.
}

function sendemail(e) {
  var data = e['values'];
  Logger.log(data); //works

  //... other code
  
  var paramslist = [email,name,actcode,date,expiry,version,link];
  var params = paramslist.join(" | ");
  var finalurl = "https://mywebsite.com/awsdata/sendemail.php?data=" + encodeURIComponent(params);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalurl);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText()); //works
}
```

What's strange is, in my execution tab, the logs for `doGet` function show empty every time. See the below image, logs for `doGet` run shows "No logs", whereas logs for `sendEmail` show what they're supposed to (as in code above) - first line is the raw list, then is the response of the `fetch` command. There's no delay in log activity, as 2-3 days old logs show same - empty.

[image]

For every condition, `return ContentService.createTextOutput(responsePrint);` prints `responsePrint` variable correctly on the screen, so the variable is not the issue. What could be the problem here? When I console.log() it, it shows. Why is logger.log() working for one (trigger) function but not the other?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your actual situation, from "if the google form linked to my sheet receives a new response, the trigger runs this function" and your shown script, I guessed the following situation.

- Your showing script is the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet or the standalone script.
- Function `doGet(request)` is run by the HTTP request (GET method) from the outside.
- Function `sendemail(e)` is run by the installable trigger of OnSubmit trigger.

Under this condition, I guessed that you wanted to achieve the following goal.

- You want to know the reason for `Why is logger.log() working for one (trigger) function but not the other?`.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following answer?

#### Answer

##### About `doGet`

In the case of Web Apps, when `doGet` is run, you want to show the log from `Logger.log` and `console.log`, it is required to link the Google Apps Script project with the Google Cloud Platform Project and/or request with the access token. [Ref (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#logs-in-web-apps-for-google-apps-script) From your question, I guessed your situation as follows.

- Your Google Apps Script project might not linked with the Google Cloud Platform Project.
- Your HTTP request for requesting `doGet` might not use the access token.

In those cases, unfortunately, the log by `Logger.log` and `console.log` is not shown in the log. It seems that this is the current specification on the Google side. If you want to see the log from `Logger.log` and `console.log`, please see the following table.

|  | Without access token | With access token |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Without linking GCP |  | Apps Script Dashboard |
| With linking GCP | Stackdriver | Apps Script Dashboard and Stackdriver |

In this table, the condition for showing logs from `Logger.log` and `console.log` can be seen. For example, when the Google Apps Script project is not linked with the GCP project, it is required to use the access token. If the access token is not used, it is required to link the Google Apps Script project with the GCP project.

##### About `sendemail`

In the case of the installable trigger of the OnSubmit trigger, the script is run as the owner of the script and the scopes have already been authorized. By this, when the script is run by the trigger, the log from `Logger.log` and `console.log` can be seen.

#### Reference:

- [Logs in Web Apps for Google Apps Script (Autor: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#logs-in-web-apps-for-google-apps-script)